# SqlAlchemy getting model name from object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an object that I'm passing to a queue to write to a database. I need to perform some logic checks to handle errors:

How can I check to see which model that object is?

```
c = Candidate(....)

type(c)
<class 'models.Candidate'>
```

is there anyway I can access `Candidates` in an `if` statement?

```
if type(c)... == 'Candidate':
```

I realize I can just do:

`if type(c) == <class 'models.Candidate'>` but didn't know if there was a cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

How about [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)?

`if isinstance(c, models.Candidate):`

This will return `True` if `c` is an instance of `models.Candidate` or an instance of a subclass.

You'll occasionally see functions that check to see what types they've received, such as:
`if isinstance(arg1, str):`
or
`if isinstance(arg1, list):`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways :

1) - By class name

```
def get_class_name(variable)
    return type(variable).__class__.__name__

var = "Hello"
if get_class_name(var) == 'str':
    ...
```

2) - By using `isinstance`

```
var = "Hello"
if isinstance(var, str):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check type of object,,, You can do like this,,,

```
class Foo:
  pass
f = Foo()
print(isinstance(f, Foo)) # True
print(type(f) is Foo) # True (also use == possible)
print(f.__class__ is Foo) # True (also use == possible)

isinstance(obj, type) # this works also on subclasses.
class Boo(Foo):
   pass
b = Boo()
isinstance(b, Foo) # True
```